# Python code getting stuck while trying to handle an exception

Tags: python, try-catch, nested-loops, nmap

Code:

```
def ScanNetwork():
        nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
        s = nmScan.scan("192.168.1.1/24", '0-4444', arguments="-O")
            
        for host in nmScan.all_hosts():
            if nmScan[host].state() == "up":
                print("Host : %s (%s)" % (host, nmScan[host].hostname()))
                try:
                    print("Version: " + s['scan'][host]['osmatch'][0]['name'] + "\nType: " + s['scan'][host]['osmatch'][0]['osclass'][0]['type'])
                except:
                    print("An Error occured while scanning this host!\nNo extra info was collected!")
                    continue
                for proto in nmScan[host].all_protocols():
                    print("---------------------------")
                    print("\nProtocol : %s" % proto)
                    lport = nmScan[host][proto].keys()
                    lport = sorted(lport)
                    for port in lport:
                        print("\nport: " + f'{port}' + "\tstate: " + nmScan[host][proto][port]['state'])
                print("---------------------------\n")  
        print("\n\nScan Completed!")
ScanNetwork()
```

Sometimes an exception occurs when the nmap fails to identify the ***Version*** or the ***Os*** running in a host. (It's a `KeyError` exception)

The part which is supposed to handle that exception is this:

```
try:
   print("Version: " + s['scan'][host]['osmatch'][0]['name'] + "\nType: " + s['scan'][host]['osmatch'][0]['osclass'][0]['type'])
except:
    print("An Error occured while scanning this host!\nNo extra info was collected!")
    continue
```

I of course assume that there's nothing wrong with nmap's output and I've again made a huge beginner mistake and that's the reason my code is getting stuck..

Notes:

- I've left the script running over night incase it returned some useful info but nothing happened!
- Please do not tell me that I need to quit using the `nmap` module and turn to `nmap3`

Having tired you with all the above, does anyone know a way to still handle that exception without the code getting stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to add the type of the exception to excpect while running the code inside the try-except block.

This should fix it:

```
try:
   print("Version: " + s['scan'][host]['osmatch'][0]['name'] + "\n" + "Type: " + s['scan'][host]['osmatch'][0]['osclass'][0]['type'])
except KeyError:
    print("An Error occured while scanning this host!\nNo extra info was collected!")
    continue
```

In case you want to catch any possible exception that could occur (and yes custom ones included) then you should use the following code:

```
try:
   <some critical code with possible exceptions to catch>
except Exception:
   print("An exception occured")
```

Comment: Oh my god I am a complete idiot.. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.. I even wrote that it was a 'KeyError' exception and somehow didn't think to check if I had added it after the except! Thank you very much for the quick answer sir!